# how to Stop Text speech on incoming and outgoing call?

Tags: android

I want stop Text speech on incoming and outgoing calls in Android. Please find my code below. it's working fine in some of the devices, but in some of the devices Text speech speaking in back ground. it's not stopped at all.
Please let me know any issue in my code level. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        try{
            TextToSpeech ttsObj=Text2SpeechBean.getTTSObject();
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                ttsObj.shutdown();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // CALL_STATE_RINGING
                ttsObj.shutdown();  
                break;
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception ::onCallStateChanged::"+e);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: add ttsObj.stop() in defaul case and in TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING case also.

Comment: Please make sure you are calling `ttsObj.stop()` and `ttsObj.shutdown()` in both `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` and `CALL_STATE_RINGING' cases

Answer (score 1):

You would initialize tts in `onStart()`, and call shutdown() in `onStop()`.
you should be able to call `TextToSpeech.stop()` or `TextToSpeech.shutdown()` in your `onPause()` and make that work. It is possible the stop fails for any number of reasons, and if it does then you're just out of luck. This works for me consistently on 6 different models of Android device.

```
@Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        if(ttsObj!= null){
            ttsObj.shutdown();
        }       
    }
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Hi Hemant, Thanks for Your replay .any mistake in  TeleListener class. My requirement based on phone call mode ,shutdown the Text speech.

Comment: above code working fine in normal cases but i want to stop text speech based on phone call mode.Please help me.

Comment: did you try my post.??

Comment: Yes. but no luck .